# Error with the __init__ file from the fit package

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a code I found on GitHub to achieve piecewise linear representation. The problem is that there seem to be an error in the **init** file of the fit package. Here's the code :

```
from matplotlib.pylab import gca, figure, plot, subplot, title, xlabel, ylabel, xlim,show
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import segment
import fit

Pull = pandas.read_csv('pull_kpi.csv', parse_dates=['pull_date'])
data = Pull[['pull_date', 'qty_late']]

from matplotlib.pylab import gca, figure, plot, subplot, title, xlabel, ylabel, xlim,show
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import segment
import fit

def draw_plot(data,plot_title):
    plot(range(len(data)),data,alpha=0.8,color='red')
    title(plot_title)
    xlabel("Samples")
    ylabel("Signal")
    xlim((0,len(data)-1))

def draw_segments(segments):
    ax = gca()
    for segment in segments:
        line = Line2D((segment[0],segment[2]),(segment[1],segment[3]))
        ax.add_line(line)

with open("example_data/16265-normalecg.txt") as f:
    file_lines = f.readlines()

data = [float(x.split("\t")[2].strip()) for x in file_lines[100:320]]

max_error = 0.005

#sliding window with regression
figure()
segments = segment.slidingwindowsegment(data, fit.regression, fit.sumsquared_error, max_error)
draw_plot(data,"Sliding window with regression")
draw_segments(segments)

#bottom-up with regression
figure()
segments = segment.bottomupsegment(data, fit.regression, fit.sumsquared_error, max_error)
draw_plot(data,"Bottom-up with regression")
draw_segments(segments)

#top-down with regression
figure()
segments = segment.topdownsegment(data, fit.regression, fit.sumsquared_error, max_error)
draw_plot(data,"Top-down with regression")
draw_segments(segments)



#sliding window with simple interpolation
figure()
segments = segment.slidingwindowsegment(data, fit.interpolate, fit.sumsquared_error, max_error)
draw_plot(data,"Sliding window with simple interpolation")
draw_segments(segments)

#bottom-up with  simple interpolation
figure()
segments = segment.bottomupsegment(data, fit.interpolate, fit.sumsquared_error, max_error)
draw_plot(data,"Bottom-up with simple interpolation")
draw_segments(segments)

#top-down with  simple interpolation
figure()
segments = segment.topdownsegment(data, fit.interpolate, fit.sumsquared_error, max_error)
draw_plot(data,"Top-down with simple interpolation")
draw_segments(segments)


show()
```

The error seems to be an invalid syntax and Python sais it occurs on the line "raise exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb".

Here is the part of the **init** file that creates a bug :

```
    # File I/O methods

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if not exc_val:
            return self.close()

        raise exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb
```

Anybody can help please ?

Comment: Hi Anaelle, please add the complete error traceback as well

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Mes Documents/LID/Projet/ScaleAI-Polytechnique/PiecewiseLinearRepresentation.py", line 4, in <module>
    import fit
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fit/__init__.py", line 53
    raise exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [`fit` package from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/fit/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/rembish/fit)) you've installed is not compatible with Python 3 (and indeed, has last been updated 8 years ago, anyway). ([Someone else is having the same problem with Python 3 with it.](https://github.com/rembish/fit/issues/2))

**However,** that's not the package you want anyway – it doesn't even export things like `sumsquared_error`.

Those exports could be found in [this `fit.py`](https://github.com/NickFoubert/simple-segment/blob/master/fit.py), that repository presumably being where you've adapted your code from.

In other words:

- `pip uninstall fit` – it's not the droid you're looking for
- copy `fit.py` and `wrappers.py` from that repository to your project's directory